# Postgresql special sequence, depending on previous values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I have this kind of data:

```
| id (integer) | coins_amount (integer) | tickets_range (text)
| 1            | 100                    | 1-101 
| 2            | 53                     | 102-155
| 3            | 555                    | 156-711
```

`id (integer)` - autoincrement sequence
`coins_amount (integer)` - providing by script, while inserting a row
`tickets_range (text)` - providing by script, while inserting a row

So `tickets_range` incrementation in the script is like this:
((previous_coins_amount + 1) + (previous_coins_amount + 1 + current_coins_amount))

I need to make `tickets_range` auto increment by the database sequence. Or is there some other method to do this kind of sequence by the database?

P.S. if string is not good for this, we can try change `tickets_range` to the array, like this:
`{1,101}; {102,155}; {156,711}`

But still, how to make this kind of increment?

Comment: I don't get it.  Strings are not incremented.

Comment: This is not auto increment, it is calculated column. I'd suggest to make it via view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if we will make an array, instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can get the ranges using window functions.  The "hi" value seems easiest as a cumulative sum.  The "lo" is then just a `lag()` on that value minus 1.

```
select t.*,
       lag(range_hi - 1, 1, 1) over (order by id) as range_lo
from (select t.*,
             sum(coins_amount + 1) over (order by id) as range_hi
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: where can I take range_hi?

Comment: Please, explain me the full query of insertion... So I need to make the insertion in one query to prevent race-conditions, if there will be some simultaniously inserts.

Comment: @user14080657 . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  This answers the question that you have here, which has to do *querying* data, not with race conditions or insertions.  If you have a *different* question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: You didnt understand my question. I don't need the query to select range. I need to understand how to solve the problem, should I need to create sequence, or create some procedures to let the database increment this values. Not from the script. Also your query isnt work, there is no range_hi value provided.